# Unable to get release title in github actions

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions, github-release

I've added github action that sends a message on our slack channel on every release.

I've managed to [get repo name and tag from github context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context), but I'm also trying and failing to get release title and release notes in that message.
I've tried these combinations:

```
${{ github.event.payload.release.name || github.event.payload.release || github.event.payload }}
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this problem?

```
name: Release
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - 'v*'
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v1

      - name: Sbt
        uses: olafurpg/setup-scala@v10

      - name: Set library version
        run: ./sbt dynver

      - name: Publish stable version
        run: ./sbt publish
        env:
          JFROG_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.JFROG_PASSWORD }}

      - name: Post to a Slack channel
        id: slack
        uses: slackapi/slack-github-action@v1.17.0

        with:
          channel-id: 'releases'
          slack-message: "Release result: ${{ job.status }}\n${{ github.repository }}: ${{ github.ref_name }}\nRelease info: ${{ github.event.payload.release.name }}, ${{ github.event.payload.release }} ${{ github.event.payload }}"
        env:
          SLACK_BOT_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN }}
```

Comment: Can you provide your workflow yml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of triggering on the tag, trigger on the release creation. That way the release information will be present.

```yaml
on:
  release:
    types: [published]
```

The tag will be under `github.event.release.tag_name`, the release under `github.event.release.name`.

Tags can be created independently of releases, that's why.

See:

- https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#release
- https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#release

Comment: Thanks for help!

I worked this way: 
tag is under:  `github.event.release.tag_name` and release name is under `github.event.release.name`.

Everything inside release object ([link](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/releases#get-a-release)) can be accessed this way.