# GitHub Actions: user that published a release

Tags: github, github-actions, github-release

Given the GitHub Actions workflow below, how can I get the username of the person who published the release that triggered the workflow?

```
name: My Workflow

on:
  release:
    types: [ published ]
jobs:
  my-job:
    runs-on: [ my-runner ]

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
       
      - name: Get username of publisher
        run: |
          # HOWTO get username of publisher
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for:

```
${{ github.event.release.author.login }}
```

See:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/70744585
- https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#release
- https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#release

Comment: Searching for "login" in the docs reveals it :D I've previously been searching the docs for "username"